# generate printer logs

Tags: printing, archive

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with an EPSON WF 2540 printer. 
The printer drivers come from the Epson Linux download centre and so far have been working ok.

The question here for me is how to log every batch of printed jobs to a directory on the side. There is a cutePdf printer on windows that I am aware of which would "print" as if a printer to a pdf file.
I would need as the printer prints and is complete to log a pdf file of exactly what was printed out so as to reprint if I need to at later stage ..etc.

How can this be done automatic under Ubuntu. I am guessing cups may be involved...